# Integrating $\int_{t}^{\infty}\frac{x^c}{\left(ax+b\right)^c}e^{-sx}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to find a closed form solution for the integral  $\int_{t}^{\infty}\frac{x^c}{\left(ax+b\right)^c}e^{-sx}dx$ where $a,b,c,s,t>0$ are real positive constants.

It is possible to find an infinite series solution by expanding $\left(ax+b\right)^{-c}$ but I am wondering if it is possible to find a closed form solution even if it is in terms of special functions. Since the lower limit of integral is not $0$, can't use Laplace or Fourier transform either. Wolfram Alpha does not return any answer unfortunately!!

Looking forward to your hints and solutions, thank you!

Comment: You can simplify into $\int_t^\infty \left(a+\frac bx\right)^{-c} e^{-sx}dx$ and factor out $a$ or $b$. If you expand as a series, you may be able to match it to a [double hypergeometric sum](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HornFunction.html)

Comment: @ТymaGaidash٠ you are right, actually we can further simplify by change of variable $sx\rightarrow x$ but still Wolfram returns no answer!

Answer (score 1):

Why not to try $$\frac{x^c}{\left(ax+b\right)^c}=a^{-c}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-c}{n}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^n x^{-n}$$ and use
$$\int_t^\infty x^{-n}\,e^{-s x}\,dx=s^{n-1} \,\Gamma (1-n,s t)$$

Using $a=1$, $b=2$,$c=3$, $s=4$, $t=5$ and computing the partial sums

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & \sum_{n=0}^p \\
  5 & 1.6495136\times 10^{-10} \\
 10 & 1.9626254\times 10^{-10} \\
 15 & 1.9549281\times 10^{-10} \\
 20 & 1.9550627\times 10^{-10} \\
 25 & 1.9550606\times 10^{-10} \\
 30 & 1.9550607\times 10^{-10} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: thank you for this answer, however I knew that It is possible to find an infinite series solution by expanding and using upper incomplete Gamma function. Is it possible to find a way to express the solution without the infinite series, for example writing answer in terms of Meijer-G function? The biggest obstacle is the integral lower limit I guess. Another thing is that the constants are not integer unfortunately, but your answer is valid for real constants too so it is okay in this regard.